# Dynamically updating datamaps fill color not working using variable as country key

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I'm having weird problems with [datamaps](/questions/tagged/datamaps) `updateCloropleth` function. I followed this example :

https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/releases/tag/v0.2.2

Here is an example of my problem. When I do this:

```
map.updateChoropleth({
    "AFG": colorx
});
```

The color updates. However, when I do this:

```
var countryx = "AFG";
map.updateChoropleth({
    countryx: colorx
});
```

It doesn't work.

I've checked that `countryx == "AFG"` returns `true`, so it's definitely the same value. The variable `colorx` can be passed fine, but passing the variable `countryx` as a key seems to break the function.

Any ideas how or why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var colorx = 100;
var countryx = "AFG";
var countryColor = {};

countryColor["AFG"] = colorx;

map.updateChoropleth(countryColor);
```

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal) - basically your problem stems from the fact that these two statements are the same:

```
var obj = {"countryx": colorx}
var obj = {countryx: colorx}
```